# Distinguish leaks from non-leaks in Chrome heap snapshots

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

When inspecting heap snapshots in Chrome developer tools or similar tools, how can one distinguish objects that "have" to remain in memory from leaks?

I'm asking this because I noticed that when executing the following code, the only fact that a class is extending another (so without any use of those), a object in the Heap is created.

```
// script.ts
class A {}
class B extends A {}

// script.js
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var A = /** @class */ (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    return A;
}());
var B = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(B, _super);
    function B() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    return B;
}(A));
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj9ap.png)

In this simple case there is only one class (B) extending the other class (A), but I tried with multiple classes (C extends A, D extends A), and in the heap viewer I see a number of A instances as many times I extends A, so when searching for leaks the things are quite confusing to me.

So my "real" question is: in a real application (Angular in my case) how can I distinguish objects related purely to - in this case - inheritance from objects leaking?

Comment: Are you comparing heap snapshots? Leaks are detected as a matter of consumption growth over time. the Timeline tool is the better tool for determining leaks. You should consider using the Allocation Profiler which combines the Snapshot and Timeline views to help you determine allocation over time.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm working on a quite big Angular project with components with common base classes and a "BaseComponent" base class in order to do common init/destroy actions application-wide, so even comparing heaps or using the timeline, in some cases it can be quite difficult to understand if some objects are not correctly destroyed knowing that some objects are there because of the inheritance

Comment: Sure, big code base, big effort. This: _how can I distinguish objects related purely to - in this case - inheritance from objects leaking?_ Leaks in JavaScript are created by dangling references - not objects or inheritance. The heap snapshot does well at showing you where references remain and where detached DOM nodes. You'll need to drill down on those to determine where the reference lives regardless of this being an object or a simple closure created by a callback. No magic bullet.